# php code with jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js line is conflict with my php functionality

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a bootstrap and php , i am using jquery to add animation to and hover effects, i added scriptwith other scripts files in footer , but due to this file my php login code stop working ,i remove it and my code start working but hover effect on my thumbnails vanished, i only added login functionality yet . when i remove jquery-latest.min link from my code , thumbnails having hover animation stop working but php code works fine , how can i remove this conflict from my code ?? i am adding  these as header and footer. In short both codes are fine but not working with each other.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap 3 Tutorial from auto-hire.com">
        <meta name="author" content="BootstrapBay.com">
        <title>Auto Hire Edge</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
        <link href="js/bootstrap.js" rel="javascript">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      </head>
      <body>
    this is footer , it has latest jquery link , wherever i added this , my php code stop working , buttons seem to un clickable

     <!-- Fixed footer -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
              <p>© 2015 AutoHireEdge.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div>

        </div>


          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

            <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
        <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
        </script>



      </div><!--container-->

    </body>
    </html>

    Here is my thumbnail code:it only work due to jquery latest.min file , added above in footer , if i remove that , hover effevt vanished


       <div class="container">
       <div class="container">
    <!---------------------------->
    <div class="text-center">
      <label class="row">Features</label>
        <h1><strong>Auto Hire Edge</strong></h1>
        </div>
           <!--thumbnail-1---->
        <ul class="thumbnails" id="hover-cap-4col">
          <li class="span3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
             <div class="caption">
               <h1>Tap To Register</h1>
               <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse" rel="tooltip" title="Preview"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a> <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Visit Website" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-share"></i></a></p>
              </div>
               <img src="images/img-thum1.jpg" alt=""> 
             </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

this is working fine , but when  i add php functionality , it stop working with each other: here is my php files of code

```
<html>
<?php
    include 'core/init.php';
    include 'includes/head.php';
    include 'includes/aside.php';

    if(empty($_POST)===false)
    {
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];

        if(empty($username)===true || empty($password)===true) {
            $errors[]='you need to enter user name and passwords';
        } 
        //check user exists or nots
        else if(user_exists($username)===false){
            $errors[]='we cant find the user with this name. have u registered?';

        }
        else if(user_active($username)===false){
            $errors[]='you haven\' t activated your account yet';
        }else{
            //check for string length
            if(strlen($password)  >32)
            {
                $errors[]='password is too long';
            }
            $login=login($username,$password);
                 if($login===false){
                $errors='this combination is false';
            }
            else
            {
                //set sessions
                $_SESSION['user_id']=$login;
                //redirect to home page
                header('Location:index.php');//redirects to home page with logged inn
                exit();
            }
         }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[]='no data received';
    }
    include 'includes/header.php';
    if(empty($errors)===false){
        ?>
        <h2>we tried you to login but...</h2>
        <?php
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    include'includes/footer.php';
    ?>
    </html>
```

file 2: loggedin

```
<!--added to index.php-->
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top pull-right ">
    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " id="menu-toggle" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>Menu </a>
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="auto-hire-edge">
        <div class="loginbutton">
             <li> <h4> <?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?> </h4></li>
             <li><button class="btn btn-sm"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></button></li>
             <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
        </div>
       <!----includes menu list ----->
    </div>
</div>
<?php include 'includes/overall/head.php'; ?>
<?php include 'core/init.php'; ?>
<?php //include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'includes/aside.php';
      include 'includes/slider.php';
      include 'includes/customer-thumbs.php';
?>
<?php
      include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
         <div id="wrapper">
         <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top pull-right ">
         <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " id="menu-toggle" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>Menu </a>
              <img src="images/logo.png" alt="auto-hire-edge">
              <div class="loginbutton">
                  <form  action="login.php" method="post" >
                     <ul id="login">    
                      <li><input type="text" name="username"  placeholder="Username" ></li>
                      <li><input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password"></li>
                     <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" id="submit">Login</button></li>
                     <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </form> 
             </div>
             <!----includes menu list ------>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Error in console??? It looks like you are adding bootstrap.js in head before including jQuery and you HTML markup suggests you are including bootstrap three times (or i don't understand logic behind your posted code...)

Comment: These are links to different files , there is no issue with these three .

Comment: I am adding bootstrap before jquery , as in sm tutorial i read that it will be fast loading of pages . Suggest better way of adding bootstrap nd jquery files plz

Comment: Ah yes, the classic "not working" StackOverflow post.  How do you expect us to know what "not working" means?  Is there an error?  Does it even attempt to load the page?  What is happening when you say "stop woirking"?

Comment: @Rida bootstrap.js uses jQuery, so you cannot include it before and so you misunderstood your 'tuto'...  And what about asked question:  `Error in console???`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: I mention it above as well , I added hover effect on thumbnails , when mouse go on thumbnail , the image is shown and animated screen go upward, I added function for it as well in js file , but jquery-latest.min is added to make it work . and php code stop working when i add jquery-latest.min . i am unable to login .

Comment: @Rida PHP is server side code while jQuery/js is client side code. Your observation seems wrong

Comment: i don't think there is error in console , i am using sublime text 2 , xampp server , window 7 with google chrome. Do u think something is wrong ?

Comment: `i don't think there is error in console` BUT did you check it??? And i told you what was wrong

Comment: @A.Wolf Mean to say their is something else i am ignoring ? their is no compatibilty issue ???

Comment: @Rida It could have incompatibility with some code pointing to older jQuery version BUT that would appear as error in console. So what happen if you include all your scripts using jQuery (e.g bootstrap.js, what about respond.js?!) **after** including jQuery, not **before**?!...  And again, i guess this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code  Take some time to read it if you don't know how to debug client side code

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
search.js:18 GET https://www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=010997258251033819707:7owyldxmpkc net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED(anonymous function) @ search.js:18(anonymous function) @ search.js:56
site.js:10 GET https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js?onload=onLoadCallback net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSEDaddGplusButton @ site.js:10(anonymous function) @ site.js:36(anonymous function) @ site.js:38